# How to build 200 Khz oscillator using Wien bridge?

Tags: oscillator

I've the following circuit for generating sine wave.

[image]

As I'm supposed to make sine wave within 1 kHZ - 200 kHz, I chose wein bridge oscillator circuit. However, I'm not able to increase the frequency, even though I calculated it with the following formula: \$f = 1/2\pi RC\$. At the moment with current parameters, got 13 Khz frequency not any more, tried a lot with different parameters but couldn't get above that. Can you please, help or suggest different circuit where, could get the needed frequency? I have to make the sine wave generating oscillator using operation amplifier or transistors. Highly, appreciate if you could assist me!

Comment: It's called W**ie**n bridge, not Wein bridge.

Comment: You might try connecting the mid-point of your batteries to ground...

Comment: Are the resistors so small they they are over loading the amplifiers output?

Comment: Wien bridge oscillators with lamps are pretty much obsolete. Look into a diode or FET based Wien bridge. Also, you may want to consider another topology like a phase-shift oscillator or a Twin-T oscillator. If you don't mind inductors, an LC oscillator like a Colpitts is also a good choice.

Comment: @PeterK Can I take then 200 kHz frequency from Colpitts circuit?

Answer (score 1):

The slew rate of a 741 (0.5V/us typical) is inadequate for high frequencies. A +/-10V sine wave output at 200kHz requires a slew rate about 25x higher than a 741 is capable of.

Try a JFET op-amp such as a TL081 or LF351.

Comment: For this circuit?

Comment: Tried both, the circuit is not working :(

Comment: Probably an inability to drive the lamp. I'd go for a jfet amplitude controller but spehro is basically correct in his assessment.